# Value type "void*' can't be assigned to entity type char error in C

Tags: c

I am getting this value assignment error when trying to compile this code and I'm not sure what the problem is. It's just a simple little function to read a line of text and build a string from it.

It was very kindly noted in the comments that I should include the actual compiler output. Find it at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readLine(int size) {
char *str;
int ch;
int len = 0;
str = malloc(size);
if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc error\n");
    exit(1);
}
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && (ch != '\n')) {
    str[len++] = ch;
    if (len == size) {
        size = size * 2;
        str = realloc(str, size);
        if(str == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
str[len] = '\0';
return str;
}



OUTPUT:
error : invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
error :   str = malloc(size);
```

Comment: Do not spam tags. Use both tags only if you ask about the difference between C & C++.

Comment: You use C++ compiler to compile C code. Use C compiler instead or force (using command line options) compiler to compile your source code as C\

Comment: With the correct includes and fixing the typo on the third to last line (that should be a zero after the backslash), it compiles just fine for me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I added the includes that I am using. Specifically it is doesn't like the 5th line where I am assigning str = malloc(size) and I don't know why..

Comment: Please double-check that the code that is currently in your question still has the error. It compiles fine for me. If there is still an error, please post the exact compiler output (including line numbers etc).

Comment: Also not really clear what this is meant to do. Seems like the 'size' parameter is a "hint" as to what size it might return. But it will realloc its way to infinity, if required. Seems odd, and maybe you're confused.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Its supposed to read a line of text is a word. When I call it I do so with a size of 16 which covers most words that I would run into but there is an off chance that I find a word longer than that so I reallocate to double the size of the array until I find the end the line. I wouldn't expect and infinitely long line of text so I should be okay there. Anyway, it does work when I take it out of the file with all my other functions defined in it, so I guess there is a problem elsewhere. My bad.

Comment: You're not bad. But you should figure out how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you posted does not have the compiler error stated in your question's subject.

Comment: @pmacfarlane 
error : invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
1>C:\Users\mitchell leefers\Documents\MyFiles\AlgosGit\Useful_Algos\CompoundWords.h(25,14): error :   str = malloc(size);

Comment: That's slightly more useful. The actual error involves a "char*" rather than a "char" from your subject line. Maybe post some more info about how you are building your code? Clearly on Windows, so I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: @MitchellLeefers The error message means that, as was already pointed out above, you are trying to compile the program with a C++ compiler, e.g. `g++`. The code is not valid in C++, but is valid in C. A C compiler, e.g. `gcc`, should not complain. Also make sure that you store the file with a conventional file ending, e.g. `.c` for C, not `.cpp` or `.cc` for C++, so that the compiler doesn't think it should be compiled as C++.

Comment: Here is the code compiled with a C compiler: [No errors](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/roGdrhdvP). Here is the same code compiled with a C++ compiler. [Errors match the ones you are reporting](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z79ec518M).

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you for the more detailed explanation! I was able to compile with GCC after I built the code outside of Visual Studio.